# Debugging mysterious device freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble finding the cause of an unexpected freeze on iOS because, if pausing the debugger, it doesn't actually pause until unfrozen. Does anyone have any idea on how to track down the actual cause of this before it completely locks up the device?

Comment: You are doing too much on the main thread.  I bet if you run outside the debugger, when this happens the app is killed by the watchdog.

Comment: The simplest answer: don't do anything on the main thread that doesn't have to be on the main thread.  For a longer answer, you need to use the Time Profiler probe with Instruments to find the hot spots.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer: don't do anything on the main thread that doesn't have to be on the main thread. For a longer answer, you need to use the Time Profiler probe with Instruments to find the hot spots.